# Python - Teradata package on 64-bit system and 32-bit ODBC administrator

Tags: python, windows, odbc, teradata

I have a problem running this code:

```
import teradata

udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="HelloWorld", version="1.0",
    logConsole=False")

session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", system="KHD_DEV",
    username="User", password="Pass");

for row in session.execute("*some valid query*"):
    print(row)
```

It gives me and error:
No driver found for 'Teradata'.  Available drivers: *list of drivers*.
I think that the problem comes from using 64-bit system while my proper ODBC drivers are in the 32-bit ODBC Administrator. The listed drivers are comming from 64-bit version of ODBC Administrator.

I think that Teradata sees my system and checks for drivers in C:\Windows\System32\odbc32.dll where i have 64-bit version installed. But the 32-bit version is under the path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbc32.dll.

I tried a few different approaches, but none of them worked:

1. By changing udaExec in my code:

   ```
   udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="HelloWorld", version="1.0",
       logConsole=False, odbcLibPath="C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\odbc32.dll"
   ```

   Exactly the same error.
2. I tried to edit Teradata package code:

   In tdodbc.py I changed: In ___init____(arguments) I tried to give him the proper path:  odbcLibPath="C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbc32.dll", but it didn't work either.

   I think that the problem might also be in:

   ```
   def initOdbcLibrary(odbcLibPath=None):
   """Initialize the ODBC Library."""
       global odbc
       if odbc is None:
           if osType == "Windows":
               odbc = ctypes.windll.odbc32
   ```

   But I don't know how to change this odbc.
3. In udaexec.py I tried to assign this path in connect function to odbLibPath variable in the part that looked like this:

   ```
   elif method.lower() == METHOD_ODBC:
                   conn = UdaExecConnection(
                       self, tdodbc.connect(queryBands=self.queryBands,
                                            odbcLibPath=self.odbcLibPath)
   ```

What do You think? Is there any way to make it work without installing drivers in 64-bit ODBC Administrator? I also tried to make package girraffez work. There also in the installation script I needed to change the paths and it worked, but then I got other problems, so I'd rather stick to teradata package.

Thanks

Comment: Can you successfully connect to Teradata using ODBC outside of Python?